# Using AppLocale with Labview in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, unicode

I am running LabVIEW 2013 Dev Environment on a Chinese Windows 8 platform. LabVIEW is not a Unicode-base program, and consequently on Asian Windows there are display issues for our interfaces created with US-English character sets. I can fix this problem by setting the language settings for non-unicode programs to English. This works fine, except that all my other non-unicode-based programs are totally illegible.

A quick google search turned up Microsoft's utility for running application with a user-specified code page, [AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13209). The utility is only written to be compatible up to Windows XP. There are two suggested methods I ran accross for installing it: 1. run installer using compatibility settings 2. install using command prompt with admin privileges (apparently it doesn't play well with UAC. You can find one set of instructions [here](http://opcode0x90.wordpress.com/2008/01/09/patch-for-applocale/) for installing AppLocale on Windows with UAC.

Unfortunately, nothing I have tried has been able to get LabVIEW to use the code page I would like it to. When I run LabVIEW through AppLocale and open the user-interface I am concerned about, the characters still do not display properly.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Could there be a fundamental incompatibility with LabVIEW?
Does anyone know of an alternative to AppLocale that might work for me?